# How to route a url to include scrolling down to a div id in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I am validating a contact form. I wrapped it in a div with the id of "contactform". When validation messages appear after submission I want the redirected page to scroll down automatically to the "contactform" div so users don't have to scroll down themselves to correct the form.

I can accomplish this easily by manually typing the url:localhost:8000/#contactform

However I cannot get the routing to work in Laravel.
I tried altering the controller to:

```
 return Redirect::to('/#contactform');
```

I tried:

```
return Redirect::to('#contactform');
return Redirect::to('/' . '#contactform');
return view('/')->with('#contactform');
return view('/#contactform');
return view('/pages.index.#contactform');
return view('/pages.index#contactform');
```

They all return without the #contactform in the url.
I know there is a javascript way to accomplish this, but I was really trying to stay away from javascript for now. There has to be a simpler way I just cannot see it. I'm new to Laravel and completely self-taught. Thanks

***EDIT
I tried a new controller step by step. Without validation it works. Validation seems to break it.

This works:

```
public function store() {
    return (string) Redirect::to('/#contactform');
}
```

This breaks it:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'telephone' => 'nullable',
        'comments' => 'required',
    ]);
    return (string) Redirect::to('/#contactform');
}
```

The top of the controller page I call the request and redirect like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

Can anyone help me get down to the reason why I cannot validate without breaking the url route?

Comment: do this `return (string) Redirect::to('/#contactform');` ... check what is displayed, do any URLS you see have the hash tag?

Comment: no. it just says localhost:8000 and loads the page

Comment: something else must be going on ... i redirect to URIs with hash tags appended with no issue

Comment: any ideas on where to start looking? The rest of the page works just fine and I haven't done much except create the form and set up the auth and contollers/routers

Comment: go to the console and go into tinker  `php artisan tinker` and in there type the same thing from above and see if the output is any different

Comment: I can't paste it here but it displayed an html with a redirect to localhost:8000/#contactform and i edited my question to include my troubleshooting effort

Comment: that is what i wanted to see, it is generating the correct URI for the redirect it would seem as it has the 'hash' attached to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On validation failure it will cause a redirect 'back'. It is entirely possible that 'back' is the same URI you want to redirect to, so from your perspective it looks like it is redirecting wrong when it is correct. If you remove the validation you should get the correct redirect.

Side note: On the server side the hash is **not** part of the URL. It is a client side thing.

Comment: Ok. Thank you as I did not know this about the back redirection. Makes sense now.

Comment: @AliciaTaylor no problem, just make sure to adjust the redirect and check again and you will know for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for me is to `compact()` a Boolean variable through the controller.

**Link example**

```
<a href="/post=5+scroll"></a>
```

**Passing the variable to the controller**

```
Route::get('/post={post_id}+{scroll}',[PostController::class, 'show']);
```

**If the variable equals 'scroll' then switch the boolean variable to true**

```
public function show($post_id, $scroll){

  if($scroll == 'scroll'){
            $scroll = true;
        }else{
            $scroll = false;
        }

  return view('yourview', compact('scroll'))
}
```

**Run the script if `$scroll` is true**

```
<script>
  @if($scroll)
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'slow');
     });
  @endif
</script>
```